# error while using Cassandra CQL: Bad Request: line 3:11 no viable alternative at input 'long'

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to create new table using following command:

```
CREATE TABLE CPU_High (
                   ... VM_MetricID varchar,
                   ... MetricTime long,
                   ... MetricValue float);
```

But it gives me following error:

> Bad Request: line 3:11 no viable alternative at input 'long'

It looks like I am using old version, can you please elaborate how to update it? 
I read that I have to copy lib/*.zip but can someone be specific? like from where and what files to which location?

Answer (score 0):

In CQL, 'long' is not a valid data type.

[Here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/cql_data_types#cql-data-types) you can find a list of valid data types. Probably, you want to use bigint, or int.